# Can't get past permissions

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api

The problem I have is that after logging in, and pressing OKAY in safari.

It can't go further! Safari is unable to open. 
https://m.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request
(in the .plist I have added the correct URL type (fb[yourappid]host)

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"myappId" 
                           urlSchemeSuffix:@"host" 
                               andDelegate:self];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
    && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}


NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"user_likes", 
                        @"read_stream",
                        nil];

if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [facebook authorize:permissions];
    [permissions release];
}
```

Picture of the login screen after login:

[image: http://tinyurl.com/chc5urf]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this and make sure you are writing the `urlSchemeSuffix` in the correct format

> urlSchemeSuffix is a string of lowercase letters that is  appended
>   to the base URL scheme used for SSO. For example,  if your
>   facebook ID is "350685531728" and you set urlSchemeSuffix to
>   "abcd", the Facebook app will expect your application to bind to
>   the following URL scheme: "fb350685531728abcd". This is useful if
>   your have multiple iOS applications that share a single Facebook
>   application id (for example, if you have a free and a paid
>   version on the same app) and you want to use SSO with both apps.
>   Giving both apps different  urlSchemeSuffix values will allow the
>   Facebook app to disambiguate their URL schemes and always
>   redirect the user back to the correct app, even if both the free
>   and the app is installed on the device.urlSchemeSuffix is
>   supported on version 3.4.1 and above of the Facebook app. If the
>   user has an older version of the Facebook app installed and your
>   app uses urlSchemeSuffix parameter, the SDK will proceed as if
>   the Facebook app isn't installed on the device and redirect the
>   user to Safari.

Comment: Already read it and added the same in the facebook app page. For me I'm using fb230940023940host (example appkey).

Comment: @Miko ,, so you are removed the square brackets from the appid? check the plist and make sure you remove them.

Comment: try to remove your app , clean and rebuild .. am very sure that the problem in the urlScheme.

Comment: Did that, deleted, cleaned and rebuilt but still the same problem.

Comment: can you please open your info.plist as source code and show me the section which is hold the urlScheme .. for sure you will put a dummy key :)

Comment: That did it, it seems like i forgot to add the underlying urlScheme and added the key just under url types! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

check directly in your app's target under "info" tab, the section for URL Types and check that if you have facebookID= 1234 the URLSchemes is fb1234.

Depending on the Xcode version it will be just one more field in the Custom iOS Target properties or it will be in a different section at the bottom called URL types